# How to redirect index page if user not logged in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Hello i create website in laravel but i facing one problem. The problem is that when user is not log in and user type www.test.com/notifications that time showing error like this

```
  ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
  Undefined variable: messages (View: /home/test/app/views/message-page.blade.php)
```

But i want to when user is not log in and enter www.test.com/notifications so user automatic redirect to index page. Please help me i very confuse.
I using the some code in base controller is as follows:

```
  public function checkLoggedIn(){
    if(Auth::user()->check()){
      return;
    }
    else {
      return Redirect::to("/");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it this way:

```
public function checkLoggedIn(){

    if (!Auth::check()) {
       return Redirect::to("/");
    }
    return true;
}
```

However I assume you want to use this function in another controller so then you should do it this way:

```
$result = $this->checkLoggedIn();
if ($result !== true) {
  return $result;
}
```

to make redirection.

But Laravel have filters so you can easily check if user is logged.

You can just use in your `routes.php`:

```
Route::group(
    ['before' => 'auth'],
    function () {
       // here you put all paths that requires user authentication
    }
);
```

And you can adjust your filter in `app/filters` for example:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::to('/');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: given the second options is already done this was not working.

Comment: @SandipKakade What do you mean? It's working for me. If you have specific problem, add more details and more code - edit your question.

Comment: I try it but i am understand how to implement this code can you explain please.
@Marcin

Comment: @SandipKakade You need to modify your routes and put your route into group I showed and in `app/filters` define your `auth` filter for example as I showed. That's it. If you put your notification route inside this group when you are not logged and open notification url in your browser you should be redirected to mainpage

Comment: i can't change my routes bcoz hole website is almost complete and my routes is like this

Route::group(["prefix" => "api/v1"], function(){


  Route::filter('auth.login', function() {
        if (!(Auth::check())) return Redirect::to('/');
});
 /* all the api is here */
}

and my filter is 
Route::filter('auth', function()
{if (Auth::guest())
 {
 if (Request::ajax())
 {
 return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
 }
 else
 {
 return Redirect::guest('login');
 }
}
});

public function checkLoggedIn(){
if(Auth::user()->check()){
return;
}
else{
return Redirect::to("/");
}}
what i did is correct

Comment: @SandipKakade I cannot help you if you haven't edited your question and haven't showed how you use your checkLoggedIn method in your controller.

Comment: i sent you the link in that link edit my question please check
url:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970753/how-to-redirect-index-page-if-user-is-not-login-and-access-another-page-in-larav
thanks.

Comment: how i redirect to other path when user not login in modules